# How do I access the lower elements of decoded JSON?

Tags: php, json, decode

I can access yyyy no problem.

```
$json = file_get_contents("JSON.TXT");
$array = json_decode($json);

debug_print("yyyy=" . $array->xxxx->yyyy. PHP_EOL )  ;
```

But how do I access `eeee`?

```
stdClass Object
(
    [xxxx] => stdClass Object
        (
            [yyyy] => r
            [zzzz] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [aaaa] => 01    
                            [bbbb] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [cccc_id] => 1
                                            [dddd] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [eeee] => 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I  would pull it out as an array and then access it. Mind you this is highly convoluted anyways. I would consider simplifying your JSON if you can

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
echo $array['xxxx']['zzzz'][0]['bbbb'][0]['dddd'][0]['eeee'];
```

If you really want the object way

```
echo $array->xxxx->zzzz[0]->bbbb[0]->dddd[0]->eeee;
```

Comment: I would still like to know how to access it the other way.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, Machavity, for taking the time to answer my question.  I appreciate your kindness.